# Why does "tail -f ... | tail" fail to produce any output?

Tags: pipe, tail

Why does the following command not produce any output?

```
$ tail -f /etc/passwd | tail
```

After reading about [buffering](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/009), I tried the following to no avail:

```
$ tail -f /etc/passwd | stdbuf -oL tail
```

Note that the following does produce output:

```
$ tail /etc/passwd | tail
```

So does this:

```
$ tail -f /etc/passwd | head
```

I am using tail version 8.21  (GNU coreutils).

Comment: What are the last 10 digits of π?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`tail` shows the last X lines.  `tail -f` does the same, but essentially in an infinite loop: on start-up, show the last X lines of the file, then using some OS magic (like inotify), monitor and show new lines.

To do its job, **`tail` must be able to locate the end of the file.**  If `tail` cannot find the file's end, it cannot show the last X lines, because "last" is undefined.  So what does `tail` do in this case?  It waits until it does find the end of the file.

Consider this:

```
$ chatter() { while :; do date; sleep 1; done; }
$ chatter | tail -f
```

This never appears to make progress, because there is never a definite end of file from `chatter`.

You get the same behavior if you ask `tail` to give you the last lines from a file system pipe.  Consider:

```
$ mkfifo test.pipe
$ tail test.pipe
```

`stdbuf` to get around the perceived problem was a noble attempt. The key fact though is that I/O buffering isn't the root cause: the lack of a definite end-of-file is.  If you check out the [tail.c source code](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/src/tail.c), you'll see the `file_lines`  function comment reads:

> END_POS is the file offset of EOF (one larger than offset of last byte).

and that's the magic.  You need an end-of-file for tail to work in any configuration.  `head` doesn't have that restriction, it just needs a start of file (which it might not have, try `head test.pipe`).  Stream oriented tools like `sed` and `awk` need neither a start or end of file: they work on buffers.

Answer (score 38):

`tail -f`'s tail is actually something unknown in the present, so how should the next `tail` know it. On the other hand `tail -f`'s head is something already known and could therefor be processed.

Or to put it simpler: `tail` is relative to the end of the file, but the output stream of `tail -f` got no EOF (at least not before its termination).

If you find the first `tail`'s pid and kill it, you should *then* see the output from the second.

Answer (score 21):

#### Technical answer

When running with a stream as input, `tail` keeps an `n`-line buffer that it fills as it reads the stream, but it cannot output those lines until it reaches the end of the stream, i.e. it receives a special `EOF` code when trying to read from the input stream. The invocation `tail -f` does not exit, thus it will never close its stream, which makes it impossible to e.g. return the 10 last lines of that stream.

Answer (score 3):

The function of `tail` is to show the last part - "tail" - of the input or file. (The option `-f` is about what it does later, so that is not relevant here.)

Let's think about a file:

What is the **last part of a file**?
Let's say it's the **last n lines** of a file.

When we read line `i` of the input file, how to decide it needs to be printed or 
not?
We do not know whether it is in the last part - because we do not know which the last line will be. So we **can not** print it now.

We need to **keep the line** until it becomes clear that is's part of the last `n` lines, or can no longer be part of it, because we know `n` further lines

If we now come to the **end of the file**, we know that the last `n` lines we kept are in fact the last `n` lines of the file.

Now, in the case of

```
tail -f /etc/passwd | tail
```

the first `tail` reads the file, and then waits to **get more data** from it, to write that out too. So it will **not signal an end of file** to the second tail when it comes to the end of the file it reads. Without that, the second `tail` **never gets notified** of the end of file, so it can **never find out** which are the last lines it should print.