# tail not working on mac terminal

Tags: tail

Due to my lack of experience with script language, (shame for a Mac user) I have referred to several sources:
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10103619/unix-merge-many-files-while-deleting-first-line-of-all-files) seemed resolved with `ls *.extension | xargs -n 1 tail -n +2`

This didn't for me, even after adding `> merged.txt` at the end,
nor the following:

```
for f in *.txt
do
    tail -n +2 $f >> /path/to/some/dir/with/files/file_name
done
```

I also tried `sed -e'1d' $FILE` in replacement of the tail command. Didn't work.

`tail -n +2 file_name.extension`, `cat LIN_1994-11_0100.txt | tail -n +2`,
`awk 'FNR != 1' *.extension` has no effect to the file.

I am uncertain if [this](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/009) has anything to do with the current issue.
Or whether the [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/154861/why-does-tail-f-tail-fail-to-produce-any-output?newreg=e2cead625e8441cd9400fcf592d5d99a) is related to the issue.

If anyone could find the reason for this problem or way out of it..would be majorly grateful. I have transferred this issue from another community here to receive more insight if I could.

Comment: So basically you want to combine several text files into one, without the first line of each file, right? Unless the file is empty I can't see a reason why `tail -n +2 FILENAME` shouldn't produce a copy of FILENAME without the first line on stdout. What kind of result do you get when running this (take a short file so you can see the result easily)?

Comment: Yes the header is the same for all all of the text files, so I intended to keep it for the first file and then remove for the rest. I get no copy file. I get nothing when I type `tail -n +2 FILENAME`. It doesn't produce error message, and the file is left untouched. (including the date modified)

Comment: `cd; (echo foo; echo bar; echo zot) > FILENAME; tail -n +2 FILENAME` works for me

Comment: Are foo, bar, zot here..different file names? (e.g. 3 out of the 264 I have) If I use this command it seems I would only be able to remove the first line of the merged, not the first line of each files that I want to combine.

Comment: `tail -n+2 /path/to/*.txt > /path/to/file_name` might be simpler, and would even sneak in a header for each file found.  Said header can be omitted with `-q`.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by 'sneak in a header' as I need to remove from each. But the issue I think should first be addressed is that, tail command doesn't function at all for a single file. Which is why I brought the post here.

Comment: As mentioned, that header can be omitted with `-q`.  And `tail` most definitely _does_ work on one file.

Comment: I have no doubt the command is supposed to work, and my issue is that it doesn't. Please read my post first. I'm thankful for the input, but I have tried most everything to no avail.

Comment: Please also read the comments :-) What exactly is the output of `(echo foo; echo bar; echo zot) > FILENAME; tail -n +2 FILENAME` on your system? `tail` sends its output to stdout (aka Terminal if used on the bash prompt) and never changes the original file, so if `tail -n +2 FILENAME` doesn't print anything in Terminal something is severely broken.

Comment: Also, when you run `tail -n +2 /path/to/*.txt > /path/to/file_name` (replacing with your real files of course) what exactly is in `/path/to/file_name` afterwards?

Comment: I have read the comments. And I have tried precisely the commands you mentioned yst. I should think that they will all work normally now. Relief..

Answer (score 0):

The stated assertion that `tail` does not work on Macs is faulty, as shown (line breaks an indentations added to `for` loops for clarity):

```
$ for i in {1..3}; do 
    for file in foo bar; do 
      echo "$i  $file" >> $file
    done
done
$ paste foo bar
1  foo  1  bar
2  foo  2  bar
3  foo  3  bar
$ tail -n+2 -q * > output
$ cat output
2  bar
3  bar
2  foo
3  foo
$ uname -a
Darwin recacted-hostname 17.2.0 Darwin Kernel Version 17.2.0: Fri Sep 29 18:27:05 PDT 2017; root:xnu-4570.20.62~3/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer originally found as edit to the question itself:

The issue was with the file format!! `mac2unix` changed the files so that `tail` command works! And [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14080306/remove-cr-line-terminators/14080764#14080764) for those who might have the same problem in the future. Thank you for all your interest and input!